# Get the HTML value which is not in a tag in c#

Tags: xml, regex, string, c#-4.0

I have an HTML string that has the following form:

```
<tr valign="top"><td colspan="2"  style="padding-bottom:5px;text-align: left"><label for="base_1001013" style="margin-bottom: 3px; float: left">Nom d'utilisateur:&nbsp;</label><span style="float: right;"><input class="PersonalDetailsClass" type="text" name="base_1001013" id="base_1001013" value="" /></span></td></tr>
```

(sorry for the formatting..)

Anyhow I need to get the value which is not in a tag. i.e.-  **Nom d'utilisateur** (without the "&nbsp", but that's neglectable).

The number of tags and their values may vary, also -  the number of words in the requested string and even their language may also vary.

I'm not sure if that's a regex question, an XML question, or a c# string manipulation functions question (don't have specific preferences) .. But I do prefer **not** using  a third-party dll (as I saw is sometimes used to parse HTML in c#).

How do I get the value?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you prefer not to use 3rd party DLL?

Comment: @tvanfosson is correct - using a regex instead of a DOM parser to parse HTML or XML will bring you nothing but pain. It's not just reinventing the wheel, it's reinventing a wheel using LEGO blocks. Regex is a great tool; it's just not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and then get the text value of the row.  That will eliminate all of the HTML elements in the snippet.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml( stringWithHtml );
var element = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes["tr"];
var text = element.InnerText;
```

Note that you may need to play around with the navigation to the desired element depending on your actual HTML.